# О "шевелилке"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Здравствуйте. 
У Шукшина встречается частушка: "Эх, милка моя, шевелилка моя; сама ходит шевелит, мне пощупатъ не велит".
Что-то неуловимо похабное слышится в этих словах, или я один такой?
Интересно происхождение частушки, и, собственно, слова "шевелилка".
Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

В  "Толковом словаре..." В.Даля (С.-П., М., 1882) я нашла:
в статье ШЕВЕЛИТЬ --- ... ШЕВЕЛИЛКА, ширялка, шутч. КОЧЕРГА. (Т.1Y, с.626). Наверное, это значение проясняет и общий смысл частушки?

Comment: Ранее я предположил, что *дело касается* девичьего бюста, но усумнился и ответ свой удалил. А чем еще может шевелить девушка, и куда тянутся руки ухажеров... У  девушков кочергов нет! Я, конечно, извиняюсь, но слово из четырех букв.

Comment: Из четырех? Мосх.

Comment: Я думаю, что слово ШЕВЕЛИЛКА в значении "кочерга" употреблено в частушке в переносном значении: Ах, милка моя, ШЕВЕЛИЛКА моя (характеристика самой девушки -- приложение!),..." Девушка побуждает молодого человека ухаживать за нею, дарить знаки внимания, побуждает к каким-то любовным действиям --- старается РАСШЕВЕЛИТЬ его, и в этом она уподобляется КОЧЕРГЕ в печи, которая ШЕВЕЛИТ угли, чтобы они лучше разгорались. А сама девушка, скромница, "пощупать не велит" (себя за известные места), хотя сама вольно или невольно вызывает такие желания у бедного парня.

Comment: Вся девушка хороша, убедили!

Comment: Какие все скромные :-) А по-моему здесь не смутный, а явный эротический намек. И на "верхний", и на "нижний" бюст.

Comment: " Слова и взор волшебниц сих
Обманчивы… как **ножки** их." А.С.П.